# Chrome extension identity.email empty

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get email and id of user through chrome identity api.

I am doing this

```
  chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userinfo){
    console.log("userinfo",userinfo);
    email=userinfo.email;
    uniqueId=userinfo.id;
  });
```

I have specified `identity` permission and have added `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` in scopes.

User is logged in through `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` and I have access token.

`console.log("userinfo",userinfo);` returns `userinfo Object {email: "", id: ""}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [getProfileUserInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) documentation says:

> - **email**: Empty if the user is not signed in or the identity.email manifest permission is not specified.
> - **id**: Empty if the user is not signed in or (in M41+) the identity.email manifest permission is not specified.

Edit `manifest.json` to include both permissions:

```
"permissions": ["identity", "identity.email"]
```

Comment: adding `indentity.email` permission helped

Answer (score 9):

In addition to having the `identity.email` permission, as posted in [the related Chrome issue for this subject](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907425#c6), **users must have their profile syncing turned on under `chrome://settings` -> People -> Sync for their ID and email to show up** using `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`.

Comment: I've the same problem with me. By the time, the user accepts the sync-in, the event has been fired (or listened) and the email_id returned is empty. Any resolution to this?

Comment: I would guess not besides them refreshing the page or whatever that is calling it.

Comment: You can add `{accountStatus: 'ANY'}` as the first parameter to `getProfileUserInfo`, the default is 'SYNC'.

Comment: @mal's suggestion was the key for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used @zachSaucier and @mal answers to solve my problem. I am now able to log the user from the background script. So in summary:

1. You must have the `"permissions": ["identity", "identity.email"]` snippet in your `manifest.json`, as well as having
2. `{accountStatus: 'ANY'}` as the first argument in your call to `getProfileUserInfo`