# Chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo randomly returns empty e-mail

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromebook, google-identity

We have a Chrome extension, which is used mainly on Chromebooks and heavily relies on retrieving the user's e-mail address via `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`. This works most of the time, but I've noticed that at random times among our customers it returns an empty field instead. Obviously I have all the required permissions in the manifest and I unfortunately haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself, nor have I noticed any patterns of when it occurs.

I'm wondering if anyone else has had similar experiences with this function.

Comment: Could it be that users are not signed into Chrome or signed with a different account? [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo) says: "The information returned is available offline, and **it only applies to the primary account for the profile**"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Iván Nokonoko's comment, also based from the same [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo), `email` is empty if the user is not signed in or the `identity.email` manifest permission is not specified.

Reference: [Chrome extension identity.email empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158084/chrome-extension-identity-email-empty)

> Edit manifest.json to include both permissions:
>
> `"permissions": ["identity", "identity.email"]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I already have all required permissions. Fact is the function works fine in 90%+ cases, it just randomly returns empty fields every now and then. I guess it's something related to the other case mentioned in the docs, but I can't figure out what and how.

Comment: only returns values if chrome sync is turned on...